# how to write result set from select to txt file?

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following:

```
$sql5 = "select *,count(*) from rc_language_type_assoc_table group by language_type_id";
$result5 = mysql_query($sql5);                           //not correct
$count5 = mysql_num_rows($result5);                      //not correct

$myFile = "/home/rainbowcode/StatsFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fh, $sql5."\n");

$myFile = "/home/rainbowcode/StatsFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fh, $result5."\n");
```

the above is not what i want, i want the actual result set of the select to print in my StatsFile
how can i achieve this please???

Comment: What does your "not correct" mean?

Comment: while ($row = self::fetch_array($result5)) and write the row array content

Comment: please do not add pseudo-tags like '[solved]' to your question title.  If one of the answers helped you solve the problem, mark it accepted.  If *none* of the answers helped but you have solved the problem on your own, post an answer of your own here and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

not the most efficient solution, but should give you an idea of how to do the job

```
$sql5 = "select *,count(*) from rc_language_type_assoc_table group by language_type_id";
$result5 = mysql_query($sql5);                           //not correct
$count5 = mysql_num_rows($result5);                      //not correct

$myFile = "/home/rainbowcode/StatsFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fh, $sql5."\n");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        fwrite($fh, "$key=>$val ");
    }

    fwrite($fh, "\n");
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Depending on the needs, he may want to use `var_export` or `fputcsv` instead of the `fwrite`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch each row and then write the values for that row to the file.